# C++ Exception Handling Guidelines

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, boost, exception

I was reading this document [Error Handling](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html) on the boost website.
in the point five i found this suggestion.

> Blockquote
>   "Don't worry too much about the what() message. It's nice to have a message that a programmer stands a chance of figuring out, but you're very unlikely to be able to compose a relevant and user-comprehensible error message at the point an exception is thrown. Certainly, internationalization is beyond the scope of the exception class author. Peter Dimov makes an excellent argument that the proper use of a what() string is to serve as a key into a table of error message formatters. Now if only we could get standardized what() strings for exceptions thrown by the standard library..."

I'm wondering on how this can be realized( in a language independent way ) but i'm not so experienced.. can you make some examples ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a very flippant attitude towards exception reporting.  But it is accurate, there just isn't much you can do with std::exception.  Getting a decent stack trace is rocket science as well.  You could use a number, encoded in ASCII.  Convert it back to an *int* and lookup a message from a `map<int, string>`.

Comment: example: message is "outofbounds", you look it up from a translation table, and display a user friendly message: "Index is out of bounds"

Comment: @HansPassant Why would you want a stack trace?  An exception isn't (or shouldn't be) a programming error, which will require debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens so often, "it depends" :-)

I find the `what()` method extremely useful in command-line applications written for advanced users (I develop scientific software). Here internationalization is not an issue as everyone understands English, and in most cases it is indeed possible to provide error messages that are meaningful to the users.

Another approach I often use is an "error class". An instance of such a class "collects" error messages and warnings while the main application runs and it prints what has been collected only upon exit. It looks like this (only the skeleton is shown to illustrate the principle):

```
class Errors {
  public:

  void add_error(const std::string& errmsg);
  void add_warning(const std::string& warnmsg);

  // print all errors and warnings
  void print(std::ostream& out) const;

  // no errors, no warnings
  bool perfect() const { return (_errs.size() + _warns.size()) == 0; }

  // no errors, maybe some warnings
  bool ok() const { return _errs.size() == 0; }

  // ...

  private:
  std::vector<std::string> _errs, _warns;
};
```

The output of `what()` can be saved directly in an `Errors` object:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
  errors.add_error(ex.what());
  // ...
}
```

or you can generate very nice error messages, possibly internationalized, in the `catch` block as you see fit by translating the output of `what()` or by using complex exception objects that encapsulate the necessary information. Then at the end of the program you can give the user a complete list of what went wrong by invoking the `print()` method.

Finally, if you write software for "non-expert users", then all the caveats noted by others above apply. Basically, internationalized, easy-to-understand error messages should be presented, and only as few as possible. You should "hide" the exceptions, so to speak. No one likes popups saying "Error #x7582764 occurred, exiting" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issues of error reporting are complex.  The comments on the
Boost site are mostly relevant to library code; there is no
really standard way of handling internationalization, for
example, so you cannot generate language dependent messages at
the library level (unless the library assumes one particular way
of handling it, which you generally don't want).  The second
point is more general.  Even neglecting internationalization, if
the exception is deep in library code, it's highly unlikely that
you could create a message which would be meaningful to a user.
In such cases, the best you can do is pass enough information up
so that the application can catch the error and generate
a meaningful message in the context of what it was doing.  Thus,
instead of something like `"no entry 'xyz' in table"`, you might
want to output `"Unknown type 'xyz' when deserializing data in
file 'abc'"`.